# jQuery .on() event catch only first element

Tags: jquery, event-handling

i have some problem with jquery events.

```
    $('.attachments').on('change', '.attachPhoto', function() {
        var container = $(this).parents('.imgattach');
        console.log($(this))
        console.log(container)
        var fileReader = new FileReader(),
            files = this.files,
            file;

        if (!files.length) {
            return;
        }
        file = files[0];

        .....
    });
```

The problem is, that $(this) is the first element of attachments list, i can't catch event on input that was triggered.

Comment: try `$(this).parent('.imgattach');` instead.  Your code WILL handle whatever is changed but you have a typo. Post a [mcve]

Comment: Can you please attach your HTML as well?

Comment: thanks for response, the problem was in another event listener in another js file.